# call a toolbar button click from another form

Tags: vb6

In VB6 I need to know how to call a button click event on anther form. The another form part is easy but how to pass the click event the proper method to "click" the right button on the toolbar is the real issue.

Here is the vent on the main form - i need to call the click event case  "Copyfrom".

MainForm

```
Public Sub tbrMain_ButtonClick(ByVal Button As MSComctlLib.Button)

Select Case Button.Index
  Case ToolBarItem.tbPrint

    '(some code)

  Case ToolBarItem.tbSave

    '(some code)

  Case ToolBarItem.tbCopyFrom

    '(some code)

   Case ToolBarItem.tbNEW

    '(etc)
```

I tried

```
Mainform.tbrMain_ButtonClick()
```

and even tried passing the index number and key - no dice.

Comment: @JeffK has explained how to do this, but it's normally better practice NOT to call event handlers, but have all event handles call a specific method for each button/external call.

Comment: @Deanna : I agree. Better to raise an event from From2, and have a handler in Form1 that does what you want. But I didn't want to clutter my answer with all of the extra plumbing. Unfortunately, it's the rare VB-er that really understands how to create and consume their own application-specific events.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The event handler is expecting to receive a ***reference*** to an actual toolbar button, so you have to pass the toolbar button itself, not it's `Caption` or `Key`, e.g.:

```
    Form1.tbrMain_ButtonClick Form1.tbrMain.Buttons(1)
```

Or, using the `Call` statement:

```
    Call Form1.tbrMain_ButtonClick(Form1.tbrMain.Buttons(1))
```

If you set the `Key` properties on your toolbar buttons, you can use the `Key` property of the desired button in place of the (1):

```
    Form1.tbrMain_ButtonClick Form1.tbrMain.Buttons("PrintButton")
```

Answer (score 0):

Private Sub Toolbar1_ButtonMenuClick(ByVal ButtonMenu As MSComctlLib.ButtonMenu)
If ButtonMenu.Key = "A" Then
MsgBox "Button-1"
ElseIf ButtonMenu.Key = "B" Then
MsgBox "Button -2"
ElseIf ButtonMenu.Key = "C" Then
MsgBox "Button -3"
ElseIf ButtonMenu.Key = "D" Then
MsgBox "Button -4"
ElseIf ButtonMenu.Key = "E" Then
MsgBox "Button -5"
End If
End Sub

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).